# update target activity of intent in notification

Tags: android, notifications

I have a notification which is pushed from background servcice, and target activity is mainactivity. But, if the user didn't touch screen more than 5 minutes, it will show lock activity.Then, if user click notification, it will display mainactivity and finish lockactivity. It's not what i am looking for.

I expect, if current screen is lockactivity, click notification, it will still lockactivity, when user input passcode, then, go to mainactivity and change to specified fragment.

anybody can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to remove the previous notification and create a new one with the other Activity.

Comment: Thanks.Do you mean update notification? but, how to keep the notification content(like "you have receive 3 messages")?